# Render component from useEffect in Reactjs/Next.js

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js, material-ui

I would like to create a global message component for my Next.js pages.

This is how I would like to render the component, just one line so I can use it across my app. With this call the component should render. I do not wish to load the component in the render part of every specific page.

The call from a page:

```js
import { MessageComponent } from '/components/message'
...
useEffect(() => { // 5000 for auto-hide message after 5 seconds
  setMessage('hello world!', 5000, ..other properties)
}
```

The component itself. The snackbar is from Material UI. I use a component so in the future i can change the implementation.

```js
export function MessageComponent({ message, autoHideDuration = 6000, severity = 'info', position = { vertical: 'bottom', horizontal: 'left', } }: MessageComponentProps {
...
return(
    <Snackbar
     anchorOrigin={{ vertical: position.vertical, horizontal: position.horizontal }}
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={6000}
      action={action}
      >
          <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="severity">
               {message}
          </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
 )
}
```

How do I implement this within an Next.js/Reactjs app? I tried `useContext` and `useRef`. It is not clear for me how I could implement this and if useContext is the right way.

(Yes I know there are NPM packages who provides this but I would like to manage my own view).

Comment: Looks like you are looking for a function style to call modal or notification? Take a look at [notfication of ant-design](https://ant.design/components/notification) and you can review the source code to learn how it works.

Comment: Besides I have written a [small tool](https://github.com/AndyBoat/functionalize/blob/main/src/index.js)  to decorate a modal-like component to be called like function,  the key concept is to create a temporary dom and use `ReactDOM.render` to render the modal component. Maybe it will help you.

Comment: What component are you referring to? What are you trying to render? Please edit your post to include all the relevant code you are working with and have an issue using as part of a complete [mcve], and provide clearer details about any issues. It's unclear what you are trying to do, so it's certainly unclear what any issues are.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your best bet is to use a reducer hook.  Look at reacts useReducer documentation, but using that you should be able to achieve what you want.

You could constantly have a MessageComponent rendered, but hidden using CSS.  You can have your useEffect for the MessageComponent looking for changes in the reducers message state, when it changes set the className of the MessageComponent to the one thats visible.  Use a setInterval to turn it off again.  The reason I suggest a reducer, is that its like the useContext hook but you have dispatch methods to mutate the state.  So in every component that will trigger a message, you can call the despatch method - perhaps also passing a payload with the message - and that will mutate the reducers state, which is being watched by the MessageComponent.

Sorry for no example code, but when I get a moment I am happy to add some!